# Any keyboard shortcut to navigate to the most recent worksheet in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working with a workbook which has got 11 worksheets. I have frequently switch between worksheets. Mostly I work between different pairs of worksheets. If I use the mouse, sometimes I have to scroll left or right to find the worksheet that I to switch to.

I was hoping that there would be some kind of a keyboard shortcut like "control + tab" available in Microsoft Excel. But I could not find anything. I also looked at the meditation but surprisingly I was not able to find anything. To me, this should be a common problem and I was hoping there would be a solution out there. Even if it is in terms of using a macro, that is also acceptable.

Thank you for any inputs

Comment: Maybe an idea: (If Microsoft hasn't destroyed it) I think that Excel opens to the last-updated worksheet. You could maybe write a VBA macro `Workbook_BeforeClose` that resets a cell to itself and saves, so the current worksheet is always the last-updated when closing and will be the current on opening.

Comment: I hope I am wrong as this really is a common problem, but I don't think there is a shortcut for this, ctrl + page up/down is better than using the mouse but still annoying when you have a lot of work sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days and trying out different variations, I have found this free utility to be the best https://jkp-ads.com/Download.asp#goback. This will not only take you to the previous worksheet, but also to any previous cell and it works with a simple keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can create some code on a sheet deactivate event to remember where you were.
Then assign a key to code that will activate the sheet you remembered.
Something like:

```
Public SavedSheetName As String

Sub GoBack()
   Sheets(SavedSheetName).Activate
End Sub

Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    SavedSheetName = Sh.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I finally found a utility which also takes you back to the previous cell and found this to be much better. I have added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a keyboard shortcut to loop through sheets:

<kbd>CTRL + PAGE DOWN</kbd>

or

<kbd>CTRL + PAGE UP</kbd>

[Mote info here](https://www.lifewire.com/moving-between-worksheets-in-excel-3124024)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, this does not take you to the most recent worksheet. It will take you to adjust and worksheets which may or may not be the most recent worksheets.